# forEach returns null independent of Access

Tags: javascript, dart, flutter

I have a problem that concerns the forEach, I can not write the result that is obtained in doc nowhere I can visualize the value I want to print (doc ["productImages"]. length) but if I change to return doc [ productImages "]. length I get null, I do not understand what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to get the size of the array and this value is in the Firebase database but the value is never saved, but I can see the value that I want using the print.

```dart
Firestore.instance
        .collection("product")
        .where("productID", isEqualTo: productID)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) => data.documents.forEach((doc) {
              return doc["productImages"].length;
            }));
```

in my debug console only returns null

Comment: forEach does not return, it just acts on all the indexes. You want map or reduce depending on what you are actually after.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` (as a method, not as a language construct) is generally frowned-upon in (pure) functional circles because its only purpose is to either mutate items (bad!) or introduce side-effects (also bad).

After looking at your code, you want to *project* from `data.documents`. In JavaScript this is done with `Array.map` (In C# it would be `IEnumerable<T>.Select`).

I’m not familiar with Firebase, but I assume `.documents` returns an `Array`, then do this:

```
.listen( data => data.documents.map( d => d[“productImages”].length ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

in dart the return type of forEach is void, it is appropriate when you need to perform an operation on each element in an array. For this case a more appropriate option would be to use map and return the result. for example-

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection("product")
    .where("productID", isEqualTo: productID)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) => data.documents.map(doc =>
          doc["productImages"]).length
        );
```

Comment: Tried the way it was put, but still with the error the error is now in the data. Documents. Map (doc = >
          Doc [ "productImages "]). length
The need to be closed
Data. Documents. Map ((DOC) = >
          Doc [ "productImages "]). length

And when closing the return is null

Comment: i don't get can you explain more?

Comment: I need to record the return value but I can not, in the code you made there is an error in data. Documents. Map (doc = >
          Doc [ "productImages "]). length 

The error corrects itself so data. Documents. Map ((DOC) = >
          Doc [ "productImages "]). length

But I still don't record the value I want and returns me null